# Need help to make a SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I have two tables `T1, T2` like below:

`T1` with columnname `ID, Description` and 
`T2` with columnname `ID1, ID2`

Here `ID1` and `ID2` are related to each other with `one to many` (ID1->ID2) relationship.

`ID1` and `ID2` both exists in `T1.ID`

Now result should be in format:

```
ID1 | ID1_Description | ID2 | ID2_Description
----  ---------------   ---   ---------------
```

Any leads will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle. Two different products, with some SQL differences.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Removed the MySQL tag. I'm assuming that if you went through the trouble of specifying the exact Oracle version, that the MySQL tag was added by mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two joins for this:

```
select t2.id1, t1a.description as description_1,
       t2.id2, t1b.description as description_2
from t2 join
     t1 t1a
     on t2.id1 = t1a.id join
     t1 t1b
     on t2.id2 = t1b.id;
```

This is standard SQL and should work in any database.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t2.id1 "TD1", t1.description "ID1_description", t2.id2 "ID2", t12.description "ID2_Description"
from t2 inner join t1 on t2.id1=t1.id inner join t1 t12
on t1.id=t12.ID2;
```

try this query and let me know if this works